# cp replace command is changing the content type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I´m executing a cp in a `Visual Studio Online` release task to change the `--cache-control` metadata, but it´s also changing the content-type of the files to `text/plain`.
Here´s the command:

```
  s3://sourcefolder/ s3://sourcefolder/ --exclude "*" -- 
  include "*.js" --include "*.png" --include "*.css" --include 
  "*.jpg" --include "*.gif" --include "*.eot" --include 
  "*.ttf" --include "*.svg" --include "*.woff" --include 
  "*.woff2" --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache- 
  control max-age=2592000,private
```

Before I execute this command, my javascript files were with correct content type: `text/javascript`, but after I execute this command it changes to `text/plain`. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a way of doing it for your specific use case. This is mainly because of different files which have different content-type value. I don't think aws s3 cp or aws s3 sync operations would work for you. This is caused by --metadata-directive REPLACE flag which is essentially removing all of the metadata and since you are not providing content-type it defaults to text/plain. However, in case you set it lets say to text/javascript, all the files will have that in their metadata which is clearly not right for images and css files.

However, I shall propose a solution that should work for you. Please try using latest version of [s3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd), as it has modify command available and you could use it as follows:

```
    ./s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header="Cache-Control:max-age=25920" \
            --exclude "*" \
            --include ... \
            s3://yourbucket/
```

More about s3cmd usage and available flags -> [s3cmd usage](https://s3tools.org/usage)